# Rearrange eigenvector matrix order when using ZHEEVD

Tags: matrix, fortran, fortran90, lapack

I noticed that when one uses the lapack subroutine ZHEEVD (or ZHEEV) the eigenvector matrix arrangement does not correspond to the eigenvalue ordering. By this, for example, I mean:

```
E = [E_1,E_2,E_3]

V = [v_3,v_2,v_1]
```

I can provide an example if needed but the question is simple: Is there some way to rearrange the eigenvector matrix such that

```
H*v_i = E_i*v_i
```

(where H is a symmetric real matrix, v_i is the eigenvector associated to the eigenvalues E_i)
eigenvalue-eigenvector correspond inside the lapack subroutines?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little surprised that the eigenvectors are not in the order of the eigenvalues, but you could try [ZHEEVX](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/d95/zheevx_8f.html). According to the documentation,

> the first M columns of Z
>             contain the orthonormal eigenvectors of the matrix A
>             corresponding to the selected eigenvalues, with the i-th
>             column of Z holding the eigenvector associated with W(i).

Of course, the syntax is a little more involved...

Comment: Yes this is also a feature that I found, you could check it for example diagonalizing a j=1, J_y Pauli matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices)